# HDR with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, ios5, core-image, hdr

I'm like to get both a real-time and post-processed HDR effect with AVFoundation and/or CoreImage. I'm assuming this is relatively easy with CoreImage once a full-frame still image is captured, but does anybody know how to achieve an HDR-like effect using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

Comment: What you mean "relatively easy"? You know a simple way to generate hdr image with iOS image frameworks? Could you please share this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AVCaptureVideoOutput` class and above mentioned delegate method (`captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`) to get each live frame from camera. From that frame, you can create CIImage and make changes using CoreImage framework; After that just draw output using drawRect: method

Comment: Do you have an example how to implement HDR?